# Issue jquery url doesnt find in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

when i use this in my jquery url it find;

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/TestJQueryTabStrip.aspx/DeleteRecord") %>',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: itemId })
 });
```

but when i want to change this to this;

```
 url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/UserControls/Order/OrderProductLicense.aspx/DeleteRecord") %>',
```

I have function into my this folder. but it doesnt fire.

```
"~/UserControls/Order/OrderProductLicense.aspx/DeleteRecord"
```

but when use folder it work.

```
'<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/TestJQueryTabStrip.aspx/DeleteRecord") %>'
```

it doesnt find. how can i resolve this problem ?

Best Regards

Comment: An obvious question, but are you sure the exact file names are in their respective folders?

Comment: i am sure filename inside my folder

Comment: Can we just clarify? Your folder is called usercontrols. Are you sure you have an .aspx page in there and not a user control .ascx?

Comment: have you specified DeleteRecord as a [WebMethod] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find my problem. my problem is my code behind function doesnt static

Answer (score 0):

try

```
'<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/TestJQueryTabStrip.aspx") %>' + '/DeleteRecord'
```